# How to fix plt.tight_layout() error while plotting multiple heatmaps

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, heatmap

I am plotting multiple heatmaps together and don't want them to crowed the space with their axes' labels. I tried to use plt.tight_layout() and it is throw some errors at me.

This is my result without plt.tight_layout():
[heatmaps without plt.tight_layout()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBJPc.png)

How can I plot these heatmaps together without them overlapping/overcrowding? What do these plt.tight_layout() errors mean?

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mbsta/Desktop/OOL_Research/heatmaptrying.py", line 125, in <module>
    plt.tight_layout()
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1406, in tight_layout
    fig.tight_layout(pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad, rect=rect)
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1755, in tight_layout
    self.subplots_adjust(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1633, in subplots_adjust
    ax.update_params()
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py", line 114, in update_params
    return_all=True)
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py", line 429, in get_position
    gridspec.get_grid_positions(fig)
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py", line 90, in get_grid_positions
    subplot_params = self.get_subplot_params(fig)
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\gridspec.py", line 376, in get_subplot_params
    hspace=hspace)
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 193, in __init__
    self.update(left, bottom, right, top, wspace, hspace)
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 228, in update
    raise ValueError('left cannot be >= right')
ValueError: left cannot be >= right
```

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import copy

#open a matplotlib Heatmap plt
ensamblePlotTitle = 'Plotting the concentration of species as a function of Temperature and pH'
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))
# the whole titlebox's title
fig.suptitle(ensamblePlotTitle)

# create x, y -> arrays that define the axes of the plots
def doit(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max):
    x = list(range(x_min, x_max + 10 , 10))
    xLen = len(x)
    y = list(range(y_min, y_max + 1, 1))
    yLen = len(y)
    return x, y

# create an empty matrix that is of proper dimension for the data
def emptyMatrix(x, y):
    matrix = []
    for row in y:
        row_temp = []
        for col in x:
            index = [col, row]
            row_temp.append(index)
        matrix.append(row_temp)
    return matrix

#below is some sample data. all data is labeled ('speciesName ') same right now for test
speciesName = 'Gly5'
vectorList1 = [[90.0, 9.0, 2.3984407629124322e-05], [100.0, 9.0, 0.00014507819388370692], [100.0, 8.0, 2.948628706668523e-05], [100.0, 3.0, 1.0490510000464058e-05]]
# speciesName AGG
vectorList2 = [[90.0, 11.0, 3.98338670007889e-05], [90.0, 10.0, 0.0001568694602997819], [90.0, 9.0, 0.00021729500208826397], [90.0, 8.0, 3.427954893498538e-05], [80.0, 11.0, 5.005800733212678e-06], [80.0, 10.0, 1.8917815211842776e-05], [80.0, 9.0, 3.260197688987888e-05], [100.0, 10.0, 0.0025925430414404384], [100.0, 8.0, 0.00012735904218293194], [100.0, 7.0, 8.764211796371061e-06], [100.0, 3.0, 6.556174300431575e-05], [100.0, 2.0, 7.130029235695392e-05], [100.0, 1.0, 2.8579516450879392e-05]]
# speciesName AG
vectorList3 = [[90.0, 12.0, 7.857065300006515e-05], [90.0, 11.0, 0.00018731032885259906], [90.0, 10.0, 0.0003595914496876516], [90.0, 9.0, 0.00016362990148175496], [90.0, 8.0, 2.834531332566035e-05], [90.0, 7.0, 1.8552701108239776e-06], [90.0, 3.0, 4.299622865498346e-06], [90.0, 2.0, 2.588271913251826e-05], [80.0, 12.0, 2.9946940577790324e-05], [80.0, 11.0, 7.045827994817115e-05], [80.0, 10.0, 0.0001310902154950886], [80.0, 9.0, 5.4234692030952545e-05], [70.0, 12.0, 2.2564659384568613e-05], [70.0, 11.0, 4.064178013275714e-05], [70.0, 10.0, 3.99009750483181e-05], [70.0, 9.0, 2.1472055129680704e-05], [70.0, 8.0, 1.4141458012117527e-06], [70.0, 3.0, 6.539410917356151e-07], [60.0, 12.0, 8.517883124497818e-06], [60.0, 11.0, 9.11130896798338e-06], [60.0, 10.0, 8.557261467856704e-06], [60.0, 9.0, 3.852707623039227e-06], [50.0, 12.0, 3.847351010155849e-06], [50.0, 11.0, 3.5498418351466194e-06], [50.0, 10.0, 2.8449405343583283e-06], [100.0, 12.0, 0.00014641664314100198], [100.0, 11.0, 0.00039152554887185394], [100.0, 9.0, 0.00043717011589104363], [100.0, 8.0, 5.702172323684191e-05], [100.0, 7.0, 4.194951754290719e-06], [100.0, 3.0, 4.116788638189755e-05], [100.0, 2.0, 0.00011746024162667303]]
# speciesName AA &/or GA
vectorList4 = [[90.0, 12.0, 5.096802681201908e-05], [90.0, 11.0, 0.0001086474552469471], [90.0, 10.0, 0.0001874050106046458], [90.0, 9.0, 3.369801732936655e-05], [90.0, 9.0, 5.286861097237001e-05], [90.0, 8.0, 1.3938341042512686e-05], [90.0, 2.0, 1.7306926679551494e-05], [80.0, 12.0, 1.889885411916292e-05], [80.0, 11.0, 4.0157802920077886e-05], [80.0, 10.0, 6.100950436853497e-05], [80.0, 9.0, 1.9450730019472016e-05], [80.0, 2.0, 8.24310336091265e-06], [70.0, 12.0, 1.3419183912788552e-05], [70.0, 11.0, 2.1882921815167904e-05], [70.0, 10.0, 1.996293802977987e-05], [70.0, 9.0, 7.807190890862633e-06], [100.0, 12.0, 9.576002374282467e-05], [100.0, 11.0, 0.0002486277660752677], [100.0, 10.0, 0.00048311682483152005], [100.0, 8.0, 1.1431446213091852e-05], [100.0, 3.0, 2.3901930552237836e-05], [100.0, 2.0, 8.24111996641259e-05]]
# speciesName GGA
vectorList5 = [[90.0, 10.0, 4.6398440762912434e-05], [90.0, 9.0, 5.527820316488004e-05], [100.0, 12.0, 1.0628799480254304e-05], [100.0, 11.0, 6.78597614738503e-05], [100.0, 10.0, 0.0002986765047101954], [100.0, 9.0, 0.0002539820873358393], [100.0, 8.0, 3.658684857766022e-05], [100.0, 3.0, 2.1463641004222935e-05], [100.0, 2.0, 3.2324005754327344e-05]]

#these are min and max values from data that will define bounds on axes.
x_min = 40
x_max = 100
y_min = 1
y_max = 12

# create x, y => arrays that will define subplot axes.
x, y = doit(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max)
# print(x)
# print(y)

# create an empty matrix of the proper dimensions for the data/subplots
matrix = emptyMatrix(x, y)
# for i in matrix:
#     print(i)

# create a heatmap subplot for each dataset (vectorList)
def createHeatPlot(count, speciesnum, matrix, vectorList,x,y):
    # 5 plots per row => 5 columns of plots
    # if more than 5 plots attempted, go to a new row
    num_columns = 5
    if speciesnum % num_columns == 0:
        num_rows = int(speciesnum / num_columns)
    else:
        num_rows = int(speciesnum / num_columns) + 1
    # print('looking at this species:', eachSpecies)

    #
    concentrationMatrix = copy.deepcopy(matrix)
    concentrationVector = copy.deepcopy(vectorList)
    for i, row in enumerate(concentrationMatrix):
        for j, element in enumerate(row):
            # compare element [temp, ph] to concentrationVector, see if in element of concentrationVector we hae matching [temp, pH]
            # if element doesn't match then no concentrated detected ( => concentration of zero), change element from  [temp, ph] to [0].
            # if element does match, change element from [temp, ph] to [concentration => animal[2]]

            # print('looking at this element', element)
            vectorMatch = 'No'
            for animal in concentrationVector:
                # print('looking at this animal', animal)
                if animal[0]==element[0] and animal[1]==element[1]:
                    vectorMatch = 'Yes'
                    # print('vectorMatch found with this animal', animal)
                    concentrationMatrix[i][j] = animal[2]
            if vectorMatch == 'No':
                # print('NO vectorMatch found with this element')
                concentrationMatrix[i][j] = 0

    # roster position of plot across the grid
    plotLocation = count + 1

    ax = fig.add_subplot(num_rows, num_columns, plotLocation)

    # give the plot axis some labels
    ax.set_title(speciesName)
    ax.set_xlabel('Temperature')
    ax.set_ylabel('pH')
    intensity = concentrationMatrix

    #setup the 2D grid with Numpy
    x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    #convert intensity (list of lists) to a numpy array for plotting
    intensity = np.array(intensity)

    #now just plug the data into pcolormesh, it's that easy!
    plt.pcolormesh(x, y, intensity)
    plt.colorbar() #need a colorbar to show the intensity scale

speciesnum = 5
createHeatPlot(0, speciesnum, matrix, vectorList1,x,y)
createHeatPlot(1, speciesnum, matrix, vectorList2,x,y)
createHeatPlot(2, speciesnum, matrix, vectorList3,x,y)
createHeatPlot(3, speciesnum, matrix, vectorList4,x,y)
createHeatPlot(4, speciesnum, matrix, vectorList5,x,y)

# This helps prevent labels of one plot from overlapping those of other plots
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()  # boom
```

Comment: Seems to be related to the colorbar, try to look into the parameters and use `ax.pcolormesh(x, y, intensity)` instead of `plt.pcolormesh` to plot the mesh onto `ax`. Try to comment the colorbar() and see if this is what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course in such cases a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is indispensable.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4.8,4.8))
for i in range(5):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 5, i+1)
    ax.set_title("Title {}".format(i))
    ax.set_xlabel('Temperature')
    ax.set_ylabel('pH')
    x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(6),np.arange(11))
    intensity = np.random.rand(10,5)
    pc = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, intensity)
    fig.colorbar(pc, ax=ax)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The above produces the error from the question.
The reason is simply that the elements of the figure do not fit into the figure. 
Choosing a slightly larger figure size makes this obvious, changing the figure width from `4.8` (the default for `plt.figaspect(1)`) to `4.9`

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4.9,4.8))
```

produces

[image]

The axes extent is basically 0; but not quite as this would result in the above error. Still, the output is quite useless. Hence a larger figure size is needed. E.g. changing figure width to `10` inch,

```
 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,4.8))
```

produces a reasonable result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I don't usually share code with anyone else, can you comment on my comments? Do you consider them OK for explaining what is going on? Ok to say they are awful if they are. Just looking for feedback to improve.

Comment: The comments are fine. The point is that the code is no [mcve], most of the code is simply completely superfluous. As can be seen from this anwer a [mcve] would be some 15 lines of code. You would not bother people to even look through all of the irrelevant stuff.

Comment: @MBS "I usually don't share code with anyone else." This is a habit to break, both at Stack Overflow and in real life. Imagine in science saying "I don't usually share my ideas with anyone else." It's the same thing with code, and for all the same reasons. Unless you work for a company with strict rules, but even then, you can share/talk with colleagues.

Comment: @eric a lot has changed over the past 3.5 years! Thank you for your encouragement.

Answer (score 0):

yFirst remove na in the dataframe and it will work with you
df.dropna(axis = 0, how ='any', thresh = None, subset = None, inplace=True)