# Show scatter plot title from column value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm making automatic scatterplot charting with regression from my dataframe example

[image]

I want to make correlation between Column2 to Column3 and Column2 to Column4 in separate scatter plot group by Column1. For example, there will be 3 scatter plot of Column2 to Column3 each with the title of A, B, and C

For the plotting I'm using pandas scatter plot for example:

```
df.groupby('Column1').plot.scatter(x='Column2',y='Column3')
```

Scatter plot return exactly 3 plot, but I want to know how to add chart title based on grouping from Column1 and also how to add the regression line. I haven't use seaborn or matplotlib yet because it's quite confusing for me, so I appreciate if you can explain more :))

**EDIT 1**

Sorry for not being clear before. My code previously running fine but with output like this.

[image]

It's ok but hard to look at which plot belong to which group. Hence my intention is to create something like this

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Shoutout to everyone who are kindly helping. Caina especially helped me a lot, shoutout to him also.

This is the code he write based on several addition on the comment.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, df.Column1.nunique(), figsize=(12,8))

groups = df.groupby('Column1')
fig.tight_layout(pad=3)

# If `fig.tight_layout(pad=3)` does not work:
# plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5) 

for i, (gname, gdata) in enumerate(groups):
    sns.regplot(x='Column2', y='Column3', data=gdata, ax=axes[i])
    axes[i].set_title(gname)
    axes[i].set_ylim(0,)
```

And this is my result plot
[image]

The title and the axis works beautifully. This thread can be considered closed as I got the help for the plot.

But as you can see, the bottom plot is in weird presentation as it also display the x axis from 0 to 600 and y from 0 to 25 although all of them should have same y axis format. For the other chart they are also stretched horizontally.

I'm trying to use the method [here](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/matplotlib/how-to-make-a-square-plot-with-equal-axes-in-matplotlib/) but not really successful with parameter `square` or `equal`

Can I ask for further on how to adjust the axis so the plot will be a square?Thank you!

Comment: you can give `plt.title{'A')` to get the title

Comment: Yes, but this return all plot to have the same title A as the title doesn't consider the subplots as different

Comment: There are a few options you can try. See documentation for visualization https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#visualization-scatter

Comment: can you share the code that results in such a variance in x and y. My chart looks different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over your groups, specifying the title:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, df.Column1.nunique(), figsize=(12,8))

groups = df.groupby('Column1')

for i, (gname, gdata) in enumerate(groups):
    sns.regplot(x='Column2', y='Column3', data=gdata, ax=axes[i]).set_title(gname)
```

You can also use [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) directly:

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='Column1')
g.map(sns.regplot, 'Column2', 'Column2')
```

---

**Edit** (further customization based on new requirements in comments):

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, df.Column1.nunique(), figsize=(12,8))

groups = df.groupby('Column1')
fig.tight_layout(pad=3)

# If `fig.tight_layout(pad=3)` does not work:
# plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5) 

for i, (gname, gdata) in enumerate(groups):
    sns.regplot(x='Column2', y='Column3', data=gdata, ax=axes[i])
    axes[i].set_title(gname)
    axes[i].set_ylim(0,)
```

Comment: HI thank you so much! This is what I need. But for both cases do you know instead of showing it horizontally to show it vertically? My actual data has long input for Column1 such as 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' and 'BBBBBBBBBBBBB' but the naming overlap with each other

Comment: Add `rotation=90` as parameter to the `set_title` method. And `g.set_titles(rotation=90)` for `seaborn.FacetGrid`.

Comment: Hi Caina thank you! I decided to stick with the iteration and the rotation works fine! But I realize for both cases the axis is way out (my data can be very small like 1.104 and 1.11 but the y axis range from -15 to 15). May I know if there is a way to make y axis start from 0 and increase horizontal spacing between plot? I tried to play with `fig_size()` in sns regplot but it only make the size smaller, not changing the axis. Appreciate if you answer this!

Comment: Hi @choohoo. Glad to help! Use `fig.tight_layout(pad=3)` to increase the space between the plots (play around with other values), and `axes[i].set_ylim(0,)` within the for loop for setting 0 as starting point to the y axis. You may also consider making subplots with multiple rows as well for better visualization.

Comment: Hi Caina. For the tight_layout it give me warning `UserWarning: Tight layout not applied. tight_layout cannot make axes height small enough to accommodate all axes decorations`. Regarding the axes, I changed the code to `ax=axes[i].set_ylim(0)` but it return error as  `'tuple' object has no attribute 'scatter'`. Have you seen something like this?

Comment: The first problem is probably related to width of your figure (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49047651/7076819)). Try increasing it within the `figsize` parameter (the first value is the width). Otherwise just uncomment the updated code with `plt.subplots_adjust`. About the `ylim`, don't assign it back to the ax. Take a look at the updated answer. Best!

Comment: Hi Caina! Thank you for the suggestion! The ylim works fine! I have another question regarding the axis formatting. I have updated the question. Please take a look if you don't mind. Thank you!

Comment: I believe your plot is stretching out because of the "C" group, but I don't know why (It should infer the x axis, not starting with 0 since the values seems to be occur around 600). I suggest you to open another question with a reproducible example of the data (as code/text) and plot.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the seaborn in-built functionality. If you want to see the correlation you can just do `df.corr()`.

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(df.corr(),annot=True) # This is HeatMap
```

[image: HeatMap]

You can also use `pairplot`.

```py
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(13.7,10.27)})
sns.set(font_scale=1.3)
sns.set_palette("cubehelix",8)
sns.pairplot(df)
```

[image: PairPlot]

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you for the answer! Yes, I have done that before but I realize this is just not the format I want to display my plot, hence I tried another method. Sorry for the misinterpretation of my question :))

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did. You can try something like this.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3,figsize=(12,6))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5, hspace=0.3)
df.groupby('Column1').plot.scatter(x='Column2',y='Column3',color="DarkBlue",ax=axes[0])
axes[0].set_title("A")
df.groupby('Column1').plot.scatter(x='Column2',y='Column3',color="DarkBlue",ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_title("B")
df.groupby('Column1').plot.scatter(x='Column2',y='Column3',color="DarkBlue",ax=axes[2])
axes[2].set_title("C")
plt.show()
```

The output of this is:

[image]

If you want to see the answers vertically, then change ncols to nrows and fix the figsize.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3,figsize=(3,12))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.2, hspace=.5)
df.groupby('Column1').plot.scatter(x='Column2',y='Column3',color="DarkBlue",ax=axes[0])
axes[0].set_title("A")
df.groupby('Column1').plot.scatter(x='Column2',y='Column3',color="DarkBlue",ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_title("B")
df.groupby('Column1').plot.scatter(x='Column2',y='Column3',color="DarkBlue",ax=axes[2])
axes[2].set_title("C")
plt.show()
```

This will give you:

[image]

Comment: Hi Joe! Thank you for answering. Your method is definitely great especially for how to adjust spacing and make the vertical. However, it's not best suited for mine since we need to assign each title manually.